# .exe from tkinter gui does not run (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

Reading a few threads helped me to create a .exe from my tkinter gui.

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I run the .exe file. The code runs normally, when I run it in vsc.

Following the instructions online I did the following steps.

1. I opened the command prompt, moved to my file location with `cd filelocation`
2. I ran the command `pyinstaller name-of-my-file.py` (also tried with the `--onefile`specification for example.)
3. I get three folders pycache, dist and build, and within build I find the respective .exe file.

As stated above, nothing happens when I run the .exe file. Also tried running it as an administrator.

Just in case, I will publish my code below.

All kinds of help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import datetime

def clicked(event=None):
    t = presentationDuration.get()
    try:
        t = float(t)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(title='ValueError', message='The string is empty or there is no number entered!')  
        return
    nSpeaker = nextSpeaker.get()
    lbl.configure(text = nSpeaker, font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
    t = int(t*60)
    update(t)
    
def update(t):
    if(t >= 0):
        m,s = divmod(t, 60)
        left_Time.configure(text = m)
        right_Time.configure(text = s)
    if(t <= 60):
        nSpeaker = nextSpeaker.get()
        lbl.configure(text = nSpeaker, bg = 'red', font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
 
    window.after(1000, update, t-1)

window = Tk()
window.title("presenters Toolkit")
 
lbl_duration = Label(window, text = "duration [mins]")
lbl_duration.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
 
presentationDuration = Entry(window, width = 10)
presentationDuration.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
 
lbl_speaker = Label(window, text = "next Speaker")
lbl_speaker.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
 
nextSpeaker = Entry(window, width = 30)
nextSpeaker.grid(column = 3, row = 0)
 
lbl = Label(window, text = "", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
 
btn = Button(window, text = "start", command = clicked)
btn.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
 
left_Time = Label(window, text ="--", font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
left_Time.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
 
mid_Time = Label(window, text = ":", font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
mid_Time.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
 
right_Time = Label(window, text = "--", font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
right_Time.grid(column = 2, row = 4)
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'clicked' is not defined` on the line `btn = Button(window, text = "start", command = clicked)` when trying to execute your code.

Comment: Try moving the function defs to before the declarations of those elements.

Comment: I just wonder why OP said *The code runs normally, when I run it in vsc.*

Comment: try running the first three lines of code separately, and then the whole code

Comment: You should not use the `exe` inside `build` directory.  Use the directory inside `dist` directory if compile using `--onedir` or the `exe` inside `dist` directory if compile using `--onefile`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code of your functions above, so that their code goes, for example, after imports. Also when running your code in the line `t = float(presentationDuration.get ())`, I found an error related to what if in `t = float(presentationDuration.get())` empty, an exception is thrown when the button is clicked `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. So I would advise you to handle this situation. Below is the code as I would see the `clicked` function. Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

```
def clicked(event=None):
    t = presentationDuration.get()
    try:
        t = float(t)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(title='ValueError', message='The string is empty or there is no number entered!')  # also you should have such line in your code `from tkinter import messagebox`
        return
    nSpeaker = nextSpeaker.get()
    lbl.configure(text = nSpeaker, font = ("Arial Bold", 80))
    t = int(t*60)
    update(t)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice on the code. Upon this, I will update my code above to make it easier for others. 
While it does improve my code, it unfortunately does not solve my problem of the .exe file not being runable.